# Groovy XmlSlurper: Find elements in XML structure

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

Let's say there is the following XML structure:

```
<Data>
    <DataFieldText>
        <DataFieldName>Field #1</DataFieldName>
        <DataFieldValue>1</DataFieldValue>
    </DataFieldText>
    <DataFieldText>
        <DataFieldName>Field #2</DataFieldName>
        <DataFieldValue>2</DataFieldValue>
    </DataFieldText>
    <DataFieldText>
        <DataFieldName>Field #3</DataFieldName>
        <DataFieldValue>3</DataFieldValue>
    </DataFieldText>
</Data>
```

Using Groovy's `XmlSlurper` I need to do the following:

Beginning from `Data` find that element which contains the value `Field #1`in the `<DataFieldName>` element. If found then get the value of the corresponding `<DataFieldValue>` which belongs to the same level.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If DataFieldName is unique in a file:

```
println new XmlSlurper()
    .parseText(xml)
    .DataFieldText.find {it.DataFieldName == "Field #1"}
    .DataFieldValue.text()
```

If it is not, and you want to get an array with all matching DataFieldValues:

```
println new XmlSlurper()
    .parseText(xml)
    .DataFieldText.findAll {it.DataFieldName == "Field #1"}*.DataFieldValue*.text()
```

Comment: very impressive, after reading this I feel compelled to go and refactor all my XmlSlurper code (curse you)

Comment: Isn't that a `List` of `NodeChildren`? Better might be: `new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ).DataFieldText.findAll { it.DataFieldName.text() == 'Field #1' }*.DataFieldValue*.text()`

Answer (score 1):

```
def xml = """<Data>    
    <DataFieldText>    
        <DataFieldName>Field #1</DataFieldName>    
        <DataFieldValue>1</DataFieldValue>    
    </DataFieldText>    
    <DataFieldText>    
        <DataFieldName>Field #2</DataFieldName>     
        <DataFieldValue>2</DataFieldValue>    
    </DataFieldText>    
    <DataFieldText>    
        <DataFieldName>Field #3</DataFieldName>    
        <DataFieldValue>3</DataFieldValue>    
        </DataFieldText>    
</Data>"""      
def payload = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)     
def node = payload.'**'.find() { myNode -> myNode.DataFieldName.text() == 'Field #1' }     
value = node.DataFieldValue?.text()    
println "${value}\n"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When you provide an answer, please include some text about why your answer works and how it differs from the solution answered before.